C# - Is there a way to temporarily protect a file from being deleted on Linux?
I am currently unit testing a piece of code that should throw an exception when a file cannot be deleted.
Here's the piece of code I am trying to test:
public void DeleteFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw FileServiceException.BecauseCouldNotDeleteFile(e);
    }
}

The test case I originally created worked perfectly fine on Windows. But our CI/CD runs on Linux images.
Here's the test case:
[Fact]
public void DeleteFile_Throws_ExceptionIfFileCannotBeDeleted()
{
    var filePath = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}{Guid.NewGuid()}.jpeg";
    using var file = File.Create(filePath);

    Assert.Throws<FileServiceException>(() =>_service.DeleteFile(filePath));

    // Make sure to delete file after the test
    _service.DeleteFile(filePath);
}

This is my current testcase. I've tried setting the UnixFileMode to None, and I've tried setting the FileAttributes to Hidden using: File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.Hidden); but none of those seem to work.
[Fact]
public void DeleteFile_Throws_ExceptionIfFileCannotBeDeleted()
{
    var filePath = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}{Guid.NewGuid()}.jpeg";
    File.Create(filePath);
    File.SetUnixFileMode(filePath, UnixFileMode.None);


    Assert.Throws<IOException>(() =>_service.DeleteFile(filePath));

    // Make sure to delete file after the test
    _service.DeleteFile(filePath);
}

EDIT:
I've also tried setting the FileAttributes to ReadOnly and UnixFileMode to None at the same time.
[Fact]
public void DeleteFile_Throws_ExceptionIfFileCannotBeDeleted()
{
    var filePath = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}{Guid.NewGuid()}.jpeg";
    using var file = File.Create(filePath);
    File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
    File.SetUnixFileMode(filePath, UnixFileMode.None);

    Assert.Throws<FileServiceException>(() =>_service.DeleteFile(filePath));

    // Make sure to delete file after the test
    _service.DeleteFile(filePath);
}

But when I dump the UnixFileMode and the FileAttributes, the UnixFileMode is None, but the FileAttributes remain unchanged and are still Normal.
Also executing shell code in order to make the file immutable and removing ALL permissions for all users/groups won't work. I've tried so using the following code:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chmod", $"000 {filePath}");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("sudo", $"chattr +i {filePath}");

Edit:
I ended up not testing this part. Thanks to the kind people that provided answers to help me out in this one.

Edit: I also tried setting the file to readonly with File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);. But this also does not seem to work.
Error Message: Assert.Throws() Failure: No exception was thrown

Does this answer your question? Why is unlink successful on an open file?

This is a Unix/Linux issue. Note the Man page for unlink which is used under the hood https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html  "If the name was the last link to a file but any processes still have the file open, the file will remain in existence until the last file descriptor referring to it is closed."

@Charlieface I purposely do not close the file in order for the file to remain opened/alive so it cannot be deleted. On Windows, this works perfectly fine, but it does not on Linux/Unix based systems. Also manually executing chmod 000 and chattr +i does work on the file, but it can still be deleted.

But Unix/LInux allow you to delete a file which is open. Under what user are you running this code, is it a superuser or root?

@Charlieface indeed, no it's not running as root or any other superuser. So it's odd to me that the code executed can still remove a file which's permissions have been set to 000 and is made immutable.

Set the file to be readonly, files can only be deleted if you have write access.

Oh shoot, just saw that I didn't provide that in my post. But I've tried setting the file to readonly using File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);. But my method is still not throwing an exception when running the tests within Linux.
